# Rails 4 Nested Forms, Error: Unpermitted parameter: order_item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

My goal is to create a new `Order` and an associated `OrderItem` using the same form.

**Models**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
  validates_associated :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

**View**

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => session[:user_id] %>
    <%= f.fields_for :order_items do |oi| %>
      <%= oi.hidden_field :product_id, :value => item.id %>
      <%= oi.hidden_field :price, :value => item.price %>
      <%= oi.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: 'form-control',     min: 1 %>
    <% end %>  
    <%= f.submit "Buy Now", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.order_items.build
end

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  if @order.save 
    redirect_to cart_path
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :custom_item_id, order_items_attributes: [:product_id, :price, :quantity])
  end
```

When submitting the nested form data to the database, the error message `Unpermitted parameter: order_item` gets returned and only the `order` data is saved.

**Update** <-- This is resolved

When I remove the "f." from `<%= f.fields_for` the form renders correctly and `order_params` includes the `order_items` data. This is interesting because the RailsGuide for Form Helpers includes the "f." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Parameter

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<TOKEN>", "order"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "order_item"=>{"product_id"=>"5", "price"=>"120.0", "quantity"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Buy Now"}
```

The data still does not save to the corresponding models.

**Update 2** <-- This is resolved

Updated the `create`action in the controller to `if @order.save!`, below is the error message:

```
Validation failed: Order items order can't be blank, Order items product can't be blank, Order items quantity can't be blank, Order items price can't be blank, Order items is invalid
```

I believe that the mistake is in this line of code `@order.order_items.build(order_params[:order_items_attributes])` but I am not sure what I need to change.

**Update 3** `Unpermitted parameter: order_item` Error message

From the terminal:
`Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=><TOKEN>, "order"=> "user_id"=>"1", "order_item"=>{"product_id"=>"5", "price"=>"120.0",  quantity"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Buy Now"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: order_item
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-03-18 14:58:21.724246"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-18 14:58:21.724246"]]
   (14.4ms)  commit transaction` 
The `order_items`data does not get saved.

Comment: You've stated your conclusion, we want to see the evidence so we can draw our own conclusions. So, please show/explain why you think what you think, some error? Something in your log? Something not behaving as you think it should?

Comment: Hi @smathy, I am not receiving any error messages when submitting the form the `else` portion of the `if` statement in the create controller gets triggered and no data is saved to the database. When I comment out this `@order.order_items.build(order_params[:order_items_attributes])` line, the `order_params` data gets saved. So I suspect that the problem is with that line of code. I might not be accessing the hash containing `order_items_attributes:` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like your association is incorrect in OrderItem. It should be `belongs_to :order` instead of `belongs_to :order_item_params`.

Second, I believe your form should say `<%= f.fields_for :order_items do |oi| %>` (`:order_items` not `:order_item`)

Finally, you should not need to do this in your controller: `@order.order_items.build(order_params[:order_items_attributes])`

#### Controller

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save 
    redirect_to cart_path
  else
    redirect_to root#url
  end
end

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :custom_item_id, order_items_attributes: [:product_id, :price, :quantity])
end
```

Comment: Great catch on the association in the model. Thanks! In regards to using `order_items`vs. `order_item`in the `fields_for`section of the view. When I use `order_items` the code in the `fields_for`section no longer appears in the view. The quantity `number_field` does not appear and the Parameters does not include the nested `order_items`. When I run the code with `order_item` in the view Parameters are built correctly, but they don't get saved to the database.

Comment: When I run the code and comment out the `@order.order_items.build(order_params[:order_items_attributes])` data for the `order` is saved, no data for `order_items` is saved and there are no error messages. When I include the `build` line, then I receive the following error message `Validation failed: Order items order can't be blank, Order items product can't be blank, Order items quantity can't be blank, Order items price can't be blank, Order items is invalid`

Comment: `<%= f.fields_for :order_items do |oi| %>`is now working, but the data for `order_items` is still not saving to the database.

Comment: You also need to build new orders items that belong to the order in your new action. The form will only show those fields if there are order items that are persisted or initialized. Or you can try <%= f.fields_for :order_items, @order.order_items.new do |oi| %>.  You may also need to add :id to the permitted params for order items for the form to work if you try to edit an existing order

Answer (score 0):

The view that rendered the form was not in another controller and not in the `orders` controller. The `show` action of tht view did not include an instance variable for `order_items`. This caused the error messages. Thank you for all of your help. For anyone looking for resources for nested forms below are some helpful resources.

  [YouTube Video Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYYwjTlcoa4)
  [API dock for fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)
  [Go Rails video for Form Nested Attributes and Fields For in Rails](https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for)
  [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
  [Rails Guide: Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)